# Datediff sql query to linq lambda query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

How do I translate this SQL function to linq query lambda expression?

```
SELECT Type, DATEDIFF(day,Expiry_Date,GETDATE()) AS Days
FROM Item
GROUP BY Type, Expiry_Date;
```

Do I first need to create a function in my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from i in db.item
group i by new{
  type = i.Type,
 eDate = i.Expiry_date
} into grp 
select new
{
 type = grp.key.Type,
 date =  grp.key.Expiry.Date.Subtract(DateTime.Now.Date).Days
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:-

```
var result = db.Item.GroupBy(x => new { x.Type, x.ExpiryDate })
                    .Select(x => new 
                                 {
                                     Type = x.Key.Type,
                                     Days = (DateTime.Now.Date - x.Key.ExpiryDate).Days
                                 };
```

Comment: @PhumlaSongxaka - You're welcome :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work